# Activerecord counting with join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have 2 activerecord relation

```
class Proxy  
   # capacity integer  
   # country string  
   has_many :configs  
end

class Config  
   belongs_to :proxy  
   # proxy_id  
   # port integer 
end
```

I want to find in a activerecord query all proxies for a specific country, where the capacity is less than his configs and order them by configs counter.

I mean I was trying to do something like (pseudo activrecord example)

```
Proxy.joins(:configs).where(country: country)
                    .where("capacity > ?", :configs.count)
                    .order_by(:configs.count)
```

I guess that maybe I'm tangled with my problem and it has an easy solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a [:counter_cache](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) in the associations

```
class Proxy  
 # configs_count integer
 has_many :configs  
end

class Config  
 belongs_to :proxy, counter_cache: true
end
```

Then you could do something like:

```
Proxy.where(country: country)
     .where("capacity > ?", :configs_count)
     .order_by(:configs_count)
```

Comment: This helps me because makes the select more light, I will do more selects than adds on the configs.

Answer (score 1):

It is [standard](https://sql.sh/cours/having) `SELECT ... JOIN ... GROUP BY ... HAVING ... ORDER` SQL task:

```
Proxy.
  joins(:configs).
  group(:id).
  having('proxies.capacity > count(configs.id)').
  order('count(configs.id)')
```